# Select2 Jquery Drop-down list

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using a "Select2" Jquery dropdown list, and when I refresh the page, the style of the dropdown field changes for a second and then rechange to the style of the Select2 (shown in the pictures below) .... I would be very grateful if you can help me with solving this issue...Thanks in advance.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppvBC.gif)

Comment: Please can you provide ajax code. if possible.

Comment: @EvilsEmpire this is the ajax code          <script>
         $(document).ready(function() {
         $("select").select2();
         });        
        </script>